# How to get title and description of a link uning HTML parsing in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, xcode4.2

As an example I have taken the below link to parse:

> http://in.news.yahoo.com/key-kiwis-players-south-african-crosshair-says-kirsten-105534372.html

& I got the page title like this:

> HtmlElement *currentElement;

```
        currentElement = [[htmlParser elementArray] objectAtIndex:0];
        titleLabel.text = [currentElement value];
```

now I need to access the content in that page. I am unable to access it because there are many div and paragraphs in that page. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What specific problem are you facing with HTML tags? What have you tried? Show us your code of what you have done and explain where you are having the problem.

Comment: Once check this text file http://cl.ly/0F0q263g1h3r0b3Q0L10   In that i am getting <title> key value succssfully,But when i am trying get text content <div> tags facing problem with subtags (for "div" tag there many sub classes and different parameters like            <div class="yom-mod yom-free-html" id="Facebook-Like-Fanpage-India"><div class="hd"><h2>Follow Us on Facebook</h2></div>)   I want access <div class="yom-mod yom-art-content "><div class="bd"> this content

Answer (score 0):

u can use this:

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

Comment: i downloaded this project, i changed url in RootViewController.m file http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss into http://cricket.yahoo.com/news/gambhir-backs-india-s-rotation-policy.html after running app in my console  getting MWFeedParser[4863:bc03] Finished Parsing With Error: Error Domain=MWFeedParser Code=3 "XML document is not a valid web feed document." UserInfo=0x4c530a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=XML document is not a valid web feed document.}